# Getting UTF-8 polish characters after serialization data using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization

I wrote script that are sending data from HTML form to server using ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    cache: false,
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

I input data into my HTML form with:
`name = 'ładna pogoda'`

My `$_POST` data in PHP script looks like: `Array ( [name] => Ĺadna pogoda )`

Data stored in MySQL: `?adna pogoda`

It's possible to convert data to get utf-8 characters in my php script after serialize() data in javascript?

UPDATE:

My MySQL table was encoded with `utf8-general-ci` but somehow my columns where I stored data was `latin1`. When I changed it to `table default` it starts working.

Comment: Is your html/php file saved with utf-8 encoding? Is your database connection set to work with utf-8? Is your database table encoded as `utf8_general_ci`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: @StormoPL Thanks for advice, my table was encoded with `utf8_general_ci` but my columns was `latin1`. I changed it and now works fine :D Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your HTML file is encoded in UTF-8 and that you declared proper charset in its head - in HTML5: `<meta charset="UTF-8">`. Making sure that your php files are also encoded in UTF-8 can be the next step if the first one does not resolve the issue.